# radio buttons as submit buttons javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button, submit, calculator

Hi I am developing calculator in javascript just for exercise purpose. this is my Html code.

```
<h1 id="h1">Calculator</h1>
<input type="text" id="vaLue" name="val1">
<input type="submit" value="+" onclick="cal()" id="plus">
<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="cal()" id="minus">
<input type="submit" value="*" onclick="cal()" id="mul">
<input type="submit" value="/" onclick="cal()" id="devide">
<input type="submit" value="=" onclick="cal()" id="equal">
```

javascript code

```
    function cal(){

    var val1 = document.getElementById('vaLue').value;
    var errormessage = 'enter value';
    var plu= document.getElementById('plus').value;
    var minu= document.getElementById('minus').value;
    var mult= document.getElementById('mul').value;
    var div= document.getElementById('devide').value;
    var equ= document.getElementById('equal').value;

    if( val1.length == 0) {

            var error = document.getElementById('error');
            error.innerHTML= errormessage;
            return; 


    }

    if (val1.length != 0){
        var bt=document.getElementById('h1');
            calc= val1+plu;
    bt.innerHTML=calc;
    val1=null;
    }


}
```

I want to use these operator buttons as submit button to be used randomly according to their functions. I thought to convert them to radio buttons with same name attribute but I don't know how to make radio button act as submit button too.

also if you can tell me how to define variable value null.

thanks for your expert advice in advance.

Regards
Dheeraj

Comment: Provide minimal, working code snippet.

Comment: You can use `onclick` on radio buttons too. Well the most correct way would be to use `onchange` on input elements.

Comment: These aren't radio buttons, these are submit buttons, which will work if part of a form. Please make it clear what you want also in respect to `cal()` function vs. submit.

Comment: "I thought to convert them to radio buttons with same name attribute but I don't know how to make radio button act as submit button too." — Don't. Leave them as submit buttons. Making them radio buttons won't help at all (but will create lots of problems).

Comment: is this the full code for calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are lookiing something like this..

```js
var sum = 0;

var inputVal = document.getElementById('vaLue');

function div() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum / inputNum);
}

function mul() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum * inputNum);
}

function sub() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum - inputNum);
}

function add() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum + inputNum);
}

function showResult(value) {
  sum = value
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = value;
}
```

```css
#result {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Calculator</h1>
<input type="text" id="vaLue" name="val1">
<input type="submit" value="+" onclick="add()" id="plus">
<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="sub()" id="minus">
<input type="submit" value="*" onclick="mul()" id="mul">
<input type="submit" value="/" onclick="div()" id="devide">
<div id="result">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sum = 0;

var inputVal = document.getElementById('vaLue');

function div() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum / inputNum);
}

function mul() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum * inputNum);
}

function sub() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum - inputNum);
}

function add() {

  var inputNum = parseFloat(inputVal.value) || 0;
  showResult(sum + inputNum);
}

function showResult(value) {
  sum = value
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = value;
}
```

```css
#result {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Calculator</h1>
<input type="text" id="vaLue" name="val1">
<input type="submit" value="+" onclick="add()" id="plus">
<input type="submit" value="-" onclick="sub()" id="minus">
<input type="submit" value="*" onclick="mul()" id="mul">
<input type="submit" value="/" onclick="div()" id="devide">
<div id="result">0</div>
```